# How to make a focus indicator for AR-App with RealityKit in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, realitykit

I'm working on an ar-app with SwiftUI and RealityKit.
I want to implement an image-asset as a customized 'focus square' to show where the 3D-Model will be placed. I've only found tutorials for SceneKit so far. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually made a Swift Package for exactly this back when RealityKit first came out.

https://github.com/maxxfrazer/FocusEntity

Comment: That looks like an excellent package, thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much!